# react hook form's getValues() returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

**The Question:**

- How do I access the form's values using react-hook-form's Controller without using `setValue()` for each input?

**The Problem:**
I'm creating my own set of reusable components and am trying to use React Hook Form's Controller to manage state, etc. I'm having trouble accessing an input's value and keep getting `undefined`. However, it will work if I first use `setValue()`.

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-nova-l3ekub?file=/src/RegistrationForm.tsx)

```
 return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <WrapperInput
        name="controllerInput"
        label="This input uses Controller:"
        type="text"
        rules={{ required: "You must enter something" }}
        defaultValue=""
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          
          // getValues() works if use following setValue()
          const testSetVal = setValue("controllerInput", "Hopper", {
            shouldValidate: true,
            shouldDirty: true
          });

          // testGetVal returns undefined if setValue() is removed
          const testGetVal = getValues("controllerInput");
          console.log(testGetVal);
        }}
      >
        GET VALUES
      </button>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
```

**More info:**

I don't understand why `getValues()` is returning `undefined`. When I view the `control` object in React dev tools I can see the value is saved. I get `undefined` on form submission too.

My general approach here is to use an atomic `Input.tsx` component that will handle an input styling. Then I use a `WrapperInput.tsx` to turn it into a controlled input using react-hook-fom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lift the `control` to the parent instead and pass it to the reusable component as prop.

```
// RegistrationForm.tsx
...
  const {
    setValue,
    getValues,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    control, 
  } = useForm();
...

return (
  ...
      <WrapperInput
        control={control} // pass it here
        name="controllerInput"
        label="This input uses Controller:"
        type="text"
        rules={{ required: "You must enter something" }}
        defaultValue=""
      />
)
```

```
// WrapperInput.tsx
const WrapperInput: FC<InputProps> = ({
  name,
  rules,
  label,
  onChange,
  control, /* use control from parent instead  */
  defaultValue,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        render={({ field }) => <Input label={label} {...field} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-haze-neyfx1)

Comment: Got the same problem, can you please explain why getValues() returns undefined even though the input has a value?

Comment: @PhilippLehmann Did you tried the above solution?